# SilverStripe 3 Boolean read only field

Tags: php, silverstripe

How do we display a `Boolean` variable in `getCMSFields()` as a read only field showing the Boolean's `->Nice()` function's values (Yes / No) ?

Here is what I have tried:

```
class EventMember extends Member {

    static $db = array (
        'NewsLetter' => 'Boolean'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();


        //WHAT I TRIED

        //$fields->fieldByName('NewsLetter')->performReadonlyTransformation();
        /*$newsletter = new ReadonlyField('NewsLetter', 'NewsLetter');
        $value = $newsletter->getValue();
        $newsletter->setValue($value)->Nice();
        $fields->replaceField('NewsLetter', $newsletter);*/

        //$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',  $nL = CheckboxField::create('NewsLetter', 'Newsletter'));
        //$value = $this->NewsLetter->Value()->Nice();
        //$nL->setValue($value)->Nice();


        $this->extend('updateCMSFields', $fields);
        return $fields;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fields->removeByName('NewsLetter');
$nL = DBField::create_field('ReadonlyField', $this->obj('NewsLetter')->Nice(), 'Newsletter');
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',  $nL);
```

Comment: To make all the fields within a FieldList read-only : $fields = $fields->makeReadonly();

Comment: Does the ReadOnlyField still contain the value? I'd try with two fields: a HiddenField to contain the value (0 or 1) for saving again to DB, and a LiteralField or ReadOnlyField for displaying the nice yes/no value in the form. Alternatively a readonly dropdown containing yes/no would work. This way you can save the boolean value and display the nice version.

Comment: in this case EventMembers have no access to the Backend. EventMembers have a separate Form on Frontend to edit their profile. In Backend only Admins can edit EventMembers. if(!Permission::check('ADMIN'))... content-authors can't edit a EventMember

Comment: wmk! but yes you are right. when creating a ReadonlyField like in my answer it does not contain the value. <span id="Form_ItemEditForm_Newsletter" class="readonly">
  Ja
 </span>